# Is Monero the first cryptocurrency to use Confidential Transactions (RingCT), 0MQ, and LMDB?

Tags: ringct, lmdb

I assume these technologies exist in other usages, but are we the first coin to implement them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> RingCT

RingCT was developed by Monero Research Labs specifically for coins with ring signatures (and even more specifically Monero). Monero is by far the most common of these, and Monero is the first to include this in their code. Keep in mind that RingCT was based on [Confidential Transactions for Bitcoin](https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt), so a coin like Bitcoin would implement CT instead.

> 0MQ

I do not know, mostly because I do not know much about 0MQ. Read more about Monero's project to add 0MQ [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/7/open-tasks/2564/0mq-by-tewinget) and what (may) be a similar project for Bitcoin [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/zmq.md). Keep in mind that I may be very wrong here.

> LMDB

There appear to be some [Bitcoin projects built on LMDB](https://symas.com/products/lightning-memory-mapped-database/involvement-in-other-projects/). From my research, though, Monero appears to be the only blockchain that uses LMDB [in its core functions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=583449.msg13138200#msg13138200).

Comment: Was Monero the first cryptocurrency to use Confidential Transactions? This is what I meant. I'll edit my question to include that change.

Comment: Likely. Keep in mind Monero will fully implement it in January 2017. Litecoin announced plans in September to support it https://www.reddit.com/r/litecoin/comments/53c0v6/confidential_transaction_for_litecoin/

Comment: I find this confusing: _"...RingCT was based on Confidential Transactions for Bitcoin, so a coin like Bitcoin couldn't implement RingCT from a technical perspective."_  – Bitcoin **could** implement CT (CT was designed for Bitcoin).  Bitcoin wouldn't need to account for Ring sigs because it doesn't use them.